# WooCommerce set default product sort to product description (content)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying have the default product sort to be by product description (content).  Right now I can make it by sku or other meta keys, but not by post content (description).  Here is what I have so far by adding this to the function.php file:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $args['order'] = 'asc';
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: no idea why you think it is possible, but it sounds like a stupid idea (pardon my french), or that you use post content in some horrible way.

Comment: as @MarkKaplun pointed out, your question is odd, so you should really expand your question to explain what you are trying to achieve, this could lead to other approaches being suggested which you may not have thought about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by content is not very efficient, as content can be long strings which take time to sort through.  However, if your description is actually very short and you want to order your results by this very short string, then you could simply store your short description in a custom meta-field and use that field to order your results.

Comment: +1 with a nitpick. string comparing is very efficient thing implemented at the CPU level (no idea if PHP goes that far, but I am making general point here ;) ) As long as the string are random enough you are probably not going to compare more than 10 characters before deciding which is "bigger", therefor the size factor is not very significant by itself.

Comment: Yes the strings are very short - (probably around 50 characters), and I am not really concerned about efficiency at this point. -If it is not possible to just sort based on content, maybe the custom meta-field idea would work. Can you give me some general guidance on how that would work? -Thanks

Comment: well here is the codex to creating a [custom order_by query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) in WordPress,  however I have never done this in WooCommerce, but see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432199/ordering-woocommerce-products-by-meta-field) and this [article](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/sort-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/) for a solution.